# Search typehead trigger time in jquery

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, search, typehead

Is there any way how to trigger the event in every 3 seconds in laravel vuejs, but I've been using Jquery in my script.The problem is when I search and input any string, since I've been using `keyup` on input type it will trigger the event every characters I've type. All I want, It will trigger when you stop typing for at least 3 seconds, else if you continued typing it will not trigger the event, is there any way to achieve this? it will very helpful for me.

Currently I've been tried `settimeout` but every time I've type will get multiple results after setting the time.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control required-field" name="driver_fullname" placeholder="Enter fullname" v-model="formFields.fullname" v-on:keyup="typehead"/>
```

*script*

```
   typehead(){
        let vm = this;
        let driveInfo = vm.formFields.fullname;

         setTimeout(() => {
            axios.put(BASE_URL + '/transportation/driver/autoComplete/' + driveInfo).then(response => {
            console.log(response.data);
            });
        }, 500);
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like what you really want is to debounce the user input to prevent an API call on every keystroke.

Check out https://www.npmjs.com/package/debounce

If you really want to delay by three seconds after the user stops typing, one way would be to use `clearTimeout()`.

Add `typeaheadTimeout: null` to your component `data`.

Then:

```js
typehead() {
  let driveInfo = this.formFields.fullname;

  if (this.typeaheadTimeout) {
    clearTimeout(this.typeaheadTimeout);
  }

  this.typeaheadTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
    axios.put(BASE_URL + '/transportation/driver/autoComplete/' + driveInfo).then(response => {
      console.log(response.data);
    });
  }, 3000);
},
```